# no value given for one or more required parameters in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I got this error

> no value given for one or more required parameters

on this part of my code

```
Private Sub RefreshData()
    con.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT pCode as [ID], lampname as [NAME],  costumer, proddate, line/shift, watts, volts, filam, base, basepos,lumen, life, atm, fuse, exp, type,testCode, textVolt, samplesize, dateStart, timeStart, LNWatts1, LNWatts2, LNWatts3, LNWatts4, LNWatts5, LNLumen1, LNLumen2, LNLumen3, LNLumen4, LNLumen5, LPW1, LPW2, LPW3, LPW4, LPW5, RLWatts1, RLWatts2, RLWatts3, RLWatts4, RLWatts5, RLLumen1, RLLumen2, RLLumen3, RLLumen4, RLLumen5, LPWF1, LPWF2, LPWF3, LPWF4, LPWF5, InspectionTime1, InspectionTime2, InspectionTime3, InspectionTime4, InspectionTime5, InspectionDate1, InspectionDate2, InspectionDate3, InspectionDate4, InspectionDate5, TH1, TH2, TH3, TH4, TH5, EL1, EL2, EL3, EL4, EL5, Dispo1, Dispo2, Dispo3, Dispo4, Dispo5, CF1, CF2, CF3, CF4, CF5, Reason1, Reason2, Reason3, Reason4, Reason5, LNAve1, LNAve2, LNAve3, LNAve4, LNAve5, LNAve6, LNAve7, LNAve8, LNAve9, LNAve10, LNAve11, LNAve12, LNAve13, LNsd1, LNsd2, LNsd3, LNsd4, LNsd5, LNsd6, LNsd7, LNsd8, LNsd9, LNsd10, LNsd11, LNsd12, LNsd13, TorqueTest, zeroHour, EndOfLife, PFCPTime1, PFCPTime2, PFCPTime3, PFCPTime4, PFCPTime5, PFCPDate1, PFCPDate2, PFCPDate3, PFCPDate4, PFCPDate5, BatchNumber FROM records ORDER by ID")

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)   -- I get the error right here

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

What would be the problem with that? Hoping for anyone to help, I'm just a newbie to vb.net..

thank you.

Comment: I'd guess you've misspelt a field name somewhere. If the field doesn't exist in the database SQL Server assumes it is a parameter. As LarsTech says below, line/shift is the probably culprit - enclose it in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting brackets around fields with the `/` character

```
proddate, [line/shift], watts, etc...
```

Otherwise, you have to painfully make sure every field you typed in your SQL string actually exists in the `[records]` table.

Given the number of fields in your query, I would think just doing `SELECT * FROM [records] ORDER BY pCode` would be good enough.

Also, make sure you use the real field name in the order clause:

```
ORDER BY pCode
```

Comment: @DerickBaquilodOperario Tried what?  The brackets or the `Select *` ?

Comment: @DerickBaquilodOperario Updated answer.  I just looked over your query again.  The `ORDER BY` is referencing ID, but ID is just an alias.  Try switching it to `ORDER BY pCode`.